# Strongly typed matrices in F#

Tags: matrix, f#

Is it possible to create a wrapper over the F# PowerPack matrix library to create strongly typed matrices and vectors?

What I mean is I want to store the dimentionality of the matrix/vector in the type itself so that I can say

**Create a function mul to multiply 2 matrices with the signature:**

```
mul :: Matrix<float, n, m> -> Matrix<float, m, p> -> Matrix<float, n, p>
```

where the latter 2 arguments to the `Matrix` type represent the number of rows and cols and are `int`s.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that `n` and `m` are values of ints, whilst type arguments need to be types.

A somewhat hackish solution would be to use a measure type for height and width.  Then it could become:

```
mull :: Matrix<float<(H^m)*(W^n)>> -> Matrix<float<H^m*W^p>> -> Matrix<float<H^n,W^p>>
```

where `H` and `W` are measure types enccoding height and width respectively

```
[<Measure>] type H
[<Measure>] type W
```